# Remove button on a particular slider in a wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

I am using a free theme. I have four sliders in my page. Thing is I want to remove a button on my 4th slider only. When I add "`display:none`", the button has been removed from all sliders but I need to remove from only one slider.

Note: This page is for a hotel so all sliders has "Book now" Buttons.

Comment: use css `nth-child`. very less info provided by you as we don't know HTML structure of your sliders and button

Comment: i am new to Wordpress, so i am trying to find where the sliders are getting placed......so what particular structure you need to solve it out?

Comment: i will basically check th HTML structure of 4th slider and based on that apply hidden css rule to it's corresponding button. You can check html structure via debugger tools of browser